# Scraping data which loaded after scrolling to bottom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm working with **PHP** and I want to scrape some data from any website. But I have a problem. I scrape data but these items number are 48. But I know that page has 11K items. Rest of datas extend when you scroll and you get new bunch of datas (48 items). 
I'm scraping with `simple_html_dom`. How can I manipulate scroll and get data ? 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the missing data is loaded via ajax.

Check the Network tab in the Developer Console (by pressing F12). Take a look at the URL which is being called (and the response), and edit it to your needs. Then call this URL instead of the one you are taking now.

Comment: Yeah, they use `ajax`. But this url gives `html` which contains these 48items. and `url` randomly changes per request.contains

Comment: Can you show URL of ajax request without domain? for example /news/48/desc or /news?onPage=48&page=1

Comment: yes sure :) `/phones?p%5B749%5D=3852` this is main path of page. and if I scroll, I can see this urls. first scroll => `/phones?cursor=1517157782.036409_5527376&p%5B749%5D=3852`, second scroll => `phones?cursor=1516889883.668711_5486459&p%5B749%5D=3852`

Comment: if possible, can you provide us with the full url,please

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible by this way.

But if you need to scrap this data you can send requests to endpoints which return lazily loaded data. You must research js code of target site.

p.s.
If you want to use really hard approach, you can research browser emulating.